# SSH client offers command to remove known host

Tags: ssh

On my Ubuntu server, when I'm about to connect through SSH to a known host with a different fingerprint, It offers me the command to remove that host from the known_hosts file. F.e. `remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/rogier/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.168.1.4`.

Unfortunately, the default SSH client on OSX does not offer this. Is it possible to add this behaviour?

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
18:7e:1f:24:5f:1d:52:b4:32:2c:ed:8e:9a:cc:0a:f7.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/rogier/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/rogier/.ssh/known_hosts:27
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/rogier/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.168.1.4
ECDSA host key for 192.168.1.4 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: You'd have to install another ssh client, obviously. Not really difficult, but you have to get active yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, the default SSH client on OSX does not offer this. Is it possible to add this behaviour?

Install more recent `openssh` from brew.

Or just remove the mentioned line from `known_hosts` file, since the command does not do any more magic than that.